# stack.peek() method- Java

Tags: java, class, stack

```
public class Coordinate{

private Integer row;
private Integer column;

public Coordinate(Integer row, Integer column){
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
}

public void setRow(Integer row){
    this.row = row;
}

public void setColumn(Integer column){
    this.column = column;
}

public Integer getRow(){
    return row;
}

public Integer getColumn(){
    return column;
}

public String toString(){
    return "<" + row.toString() + "," + column.toString() + ">";
}
}
```

ok so i have this coordinate class and i have some of them pushed onto a stack. now what i want to do is peek() at one of them and be able to use the getRow and getColumn method at the one i peek at. How do i do this? The problem i am having is i am creating a new instance of Coordinate and then assigning stack.peek() to it and then using the methods on it but that not working. Confused

Comment: The definition of `Coordinate` isn't really relevant; push an instance of it onto a stack, then call a coords method from the results of the `peek` call: `stack.peek().getColumn()`.

Comment: Or are you trying to just call stack methods as Bill's answer demonstrates? The question isn't really clear.

Comment: i tried to do System.out.println(stack.peek().getRow());
but got error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.println(mazeStack.peek().getRow());
                                     ^
  symbol:   method getRow()
  location: class Object

Comment: Totally can't read that; edit the question. Looks like you declared your stack incorrectly, though--see Bill's answer.

Comment: I created my own Stack Class i do not use the one in java.util

Comment: And i can print stack.peek() just fine, what i am trying to do is peek at it and use getRow and getColumn methods on it once i peek at it

Comment: @JohnSmith If you created your own `Stack` class, post that code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(1,2);
Stack<Coordinate> s = new Stack<Coordinate>();
s.push(c);
System.out.println(s.peek());

Coordinate c2 = (Coordinate)s.pop();
System.out.println(c2);
System.out.println(c2.getRow());
```

Here's a tip though, don't use java.util.Stack. Its from the original collections library which wasn't very good.

*edit* modified to represent the cast, which is what it sounds like you need in this case. Note c and c2 will point to the same object.

Comment: The OP made his own `Stack` class

Comment: Looks like he did, but he didn't say that until later.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have to cast the result of stack.peek() to your Coordinate class. Something like `System.out.println(((Coordinate)mazeStack.peek()).getRow());` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That is, if your implementation of stack.peek() actually returns an Object.

Comment: Yes thank you so much! I forgot about casts. Solved my problem